# Why does matplotlib not show specific math text

Tags: python, matplotlib, math

I'm trying to write a title that looks like this:

`plt.title(f'Title \n $\mu=1$')`

[image: title 1]

**But instead with "mu" I want to use Beta.**

`plt.title(f'Title \n $\beta=1$')`

**And gives me this error:**

`ValueError:  eta=1$ ^ Expected end of text, found '$'  (at char 1), (line:1, col:2)`

I have read the docs (https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/text/mathtext.html) and:

`plt.title(r'$\alpha > \beta$')`

Should work, any idea why it doesn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the string raw to shield away special symbols like \b, \t, \n etc (that r symbol in r"\beta").

Alternatively, duplicate the backslash in \beta

Comment: didn't know about the duplicate backslash, worked like charm. thanks for the quick answer!